# python mysql update using inner join

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

This query does not work in `PyMysql`, I cannot seem to find the problem.

```
query = """UPDATE user INNER JOIN identification_card ON user.id = %s SET user.id_type = %s, user.validity = %s"""
data = (identification_card.user_id, identification_card.card_type, identification_card.expiry_date)
cursor.execute(query,data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you are passing  column name and not value

or you simple use the joined  column name for values

```
  UPDATE user 
  INNER JOIN identification_card ON user.id = identification_card.user_id 
  SET user.id_type = identification_card.card_type 
  user.validity = identification_card.expiry_date 




query = """UPDATE user 
  INNER JOIN identification_card ON user.id = identification_card.user_id 
  SET user.id_type = identification_card.card_type 
  user.validity = identification_card.expiry_date"""

cursor.execute(query,data)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I tried assigning the value from a select query then passing it to the update query. Thank you very much